# Where is the exported .pfx file?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out file.pfx -in ssl.txt
```

It asks for a password, I enter something random and then again and then the command finishes. Where's the file though?

This is on Windows.

Comment: Try `updatedb ; locate file.pfx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha... I was running openssl in a folder that requires administrator privileges but didn't run it as an administrator.